# Azure: BadRequest: Last endpoint can not be removed from reserved VIP

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I do not know how but the Azure allows you to enter two identical endpoints in different VMS, for the same VIP. Now I can not remove these endpoints. Does anyone have any idea how should I do?

**EndPoints**
[image: Endpoints]

**Error when removing EndPoints**
[image: Error when removing EndPoints]

I've tried also remove VIPs and Reserved IPs...

Answer (score 1):

I have to mention that I have not tried it myself, but it looks like the command you need to run prior to deleting the endpoint is

```
Remove-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName $rip -ServiceName $service -VirtualIPName $vip
```